# Windows Phone: Adding XAML Tags by C#-Commands

Tags: c#, xaml, variables, windows-phone-8

Windows Phone 8 App (C#):

- I have an Array with Peoples First Name, Last Name and Employee Number.
- This Array **does not have a fixed length**.
- In XAML, I'm trying to show a list of all peoples names, linking to a Page where we'll need their Employee Number.

**Now, does anyone have an idea if it's possible to only add as many XAML TextBlocks as the Array length?**

They would look like this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="first" Text=""  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,(*X*+50),0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="50" Width="445"/>
```

The girl who started developing this App simply put in 30 TextBlock-Tags and used maaany if-statements in order to fill these, if data was available for those. Is this the only possible solution? :(

Thank you so much for your help!
Kind Regards,
Rebecca

Comment: Hey what's that operand on your margin? That (*X*+50)? I've never seen that done before, would like to learn something new today :)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I meant to say that X is a variable, so our margin would always be  x = x+50

Comment: That's pretty cool, I never even thought to try that before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Xaml Code**

```
   <ListBox x:Name="lstbx">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" Foreground="Red"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" Foreground="Green"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding EmployeeNumber}" Foreground="Blue"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**c# code**

```
public class Person
{
    public string  FirstName { get; set; }
    public string  LastName { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }

    public Person(string FirstName, string LastName, int EmployeeNumber)
    {
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
        this.EmployeeNumber = EmployeeNumber;
    }
}

       protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {      
        var data = new Person[]
       {
           new Person("Fistname1","LastName1",1),
           new Person("Fistname2","LastName2",2),
           new Person("Fistname3","LastName3",3),
           new Person("Fistname4","LastName4",4),
       };
        lstbx.ItemsSource = data;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use a loop like this

`foreach(string s in ArrayName)
    {
       TextBlock TB = new Textblock();
       // set all the properties of the textblock like
       TB.width= SOMEVALUE;
       TB.height=SOMEVALUE;
       .....
       .....
       .....
       .....
       // once you are done
       // just put that Textblock as a child of the wrapper
       //say you have a grid wrapping all your textboxes , then
       GRID.children.add(TB);`

}

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could use a for loop in your code to create a new textblock for each item in the array. You may be better using a `List<T>` or an observable collection, as these are easier to iterate than an array.

The code would be something like:

```
 foreach (string item in myList)
        {
          var tb = new TextBlock();
              tb.Text = item
        }
```

This is pseudo code but hopefully you get the idea

Comment: Or if you would like to stick to using an array, post the code where the array is defined and added to and ill take a look